# How to compare months of two dates in crystal report

Tags: date, crystal-reports

I have seven dates on my crystal report.I need to compare month of each date with the date the report is made to run(@Datebeg is the field for report date).
I am using formula on my report as

```
    if month({Date1})=month(cdate({@Datebeg})) and 
month({Date2})=month(cdate({@Datebeg})) and 
month({Date3})=month(cdate({@Datebeg})) and 
month({Date4})=month(cdate({@Datebeg})) and 
month({Date5})=month(cdate({@Datebeg})) and 
month({Date6})=month(cdate({@Datebeg})) and
month({Date7})=month(cdate({@Datebeg}))
then (H1+H2+H3+H4+H5+H6+H7) else 1.
```

The output I am getting is 1,each time.The months are not getting compared at all.If I put OR instead of AND,that gives me sum of all H(1..7).
Please help me with the comparison.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it shouldn't matter, but you can compare months 2 -> 7 with `month({date1})` instead of `month(cdate({@Dagebeg}))`  Try removing month 7, then 6, then 5, etc., until you get the behavior you expect.  Maybe one of the month values is different, or you need to test for NULL.

Comment: Hello , I am doing the same on my report,I have made 7 of such formulae and in each one I am removing first the 7th,then (6th and 7th),then (7th,6th,5th) then (7th,6th,5th,4th)then (7th,6th,5th,4th,3rd) and lastly (7th,6th,5th,4th,3rd,2nd )dates .The formulae on report gives "no error" but the actual comparison is not taking place.

Comment: do any of those formula seem to work?  even the first comparison?

Comment: No.It gave 1 each time.

Comment: I tried to compare the two conditions :if month({Date1})=month(cdate({@Datebeg})) and 
month({Date2})=month(cdate({@Datebeg})) then (H1+H2) else 1,it gave me the summation ,but as I add Date3 to the above formula its starts giving 1.Probably,its not comparing more than two values at a time or I may placing the brackets in a wrong way.Please help me how to compare three or more conditions here.

Comment: try adding a formula that only shows month(cdate({@Datebeg})) so you can confirm your parameter value is coming across as you expect.  Just so you know, there's nothing wrong with your syntax.  it's the values that are causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

go ahead and create 7 formulas and put a condition per formula, for example:

```
@Formula1
month({Date1})=month(cdate({@Datebeg}))
@Formula2
month({Date3})=month(cdate({@Datebeg}))
```

so on and so forth. Place those formulas in you report header and run the report. In that way you can see the behavior of each condition and troubleshoot it. Those formulas are going to return `True or False`, True when they meet the criteria and False if they don't.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi,I did as you told,its matching for first two Dates(Date1 & Date2),then condition fails,due to presence of AND it gives 0,its not going to the else part,but I guess it should.I had written the else part as :